# nth root of a number based on two user inputs

Tags: c#, math

```
var result6 = Math.Sqrt(num1, num2);
Console.Write(name + " this is the final result of square rooting = "+ result6);
```

I would like to find the nth root of a number based on two user inputs. I am trying to use the `Math.Sqrt()` method to achieve this.

This piece of script is outputting an error `No overload for method 'Sqrt' takes 2 arguments [Main2]`, is there a method to fix this error?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Sqrt_System_Double_

Comment: Did you read up on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes, remove the second parameter. See docs for [Math.Sqrt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netcore-3.1). What are you expecting to happen with two parameters?

Comment: But the example in the document is just squaring the double by 2...But what if you want the user inputs first number to get square rooted by his second double input?

Comment: "first number to get square rooted by his second double input" - sorry, what?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe he means nth root, like cube root or fourth root, n being the user's second input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Sqrt_System_Double_) the `Math.sqrt(double)` method only takes one parameter, no overloads.

If you meant to take the nth root, you could use [`Math.Pow(Double, Double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netcore-3.1) and put 1 over the second parameter, such as

```
Math.Pow(64, 1/3); // Cube root of 64
// Output: 4
```

Comment: @TheGeneral The OP might want to read the docs for more information, and can remove a parameter from his method call. The OP would need to provide more information, for example, if they meant to get the nth root.